# How to write custom handler (axis2 handler) to read custom headers message and validate user/password against the user store in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart, wso2-esb

I wish to add custom handler  (axis2 handler) for  to read custom headers in my message and validate user/password against the user store.
How  would i achieve this.
My request security header will come like this

```
<soapenv:Header>
          <pr:authent soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://hh.eeeee.com/hh">
             <pr:user>ssp</pr:user>
             <pr:password>MW</pr:password>
          </pr:authent>
       </soapenv:Header>
```

Where as wso2 esb expecting WSSE standard format so the request is like this

<

```
soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-4">
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-06-02T08:38:41Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">byWKVY4stEATvTqaoNMswQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21.304Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse: >
   </soapenv:Header>
```

How would i change the header as per wso2 standard or how to write security policy as per my client request for validating aganist of default userstore.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you simply need to authenticate a user against a user store, you could directly use the `AuthenticationAdmin` service. It expects the username/password as part of the soap body. So, use PayloadFactory mediator to generate the message body, set the user/password you extract from the request as args to PF mediator, and call the AuthnetiationAdmin.

Comment: Thanks for replay Kasun! This solution i know just need to send username&password to some other endpoint But this functionality with in the InSequence where as i am looking before proxy only like Username-token do

Comment: Yes.. so, you can add WS-Sec to an ESB endpoint, so the request from esb to back-end will be populated with security headers. Need to think how to inject your params to that request

Comment: Thank for Replay ,Is there no way to handle in Synapse Level